# Error parse result odbc query

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I have this code:

```
     case catch ejabberd_odbc:sql_query(
                     Server,
                     ["select COUNT(*) as total from users "
                      "where username='", IdUsername, "'"]) of
            {selected, [<<"total">>], [{Totale}]} ->
                io:format(Totale);
            _ ->
                io:format("err")
     end,
```

but always print "err" to console, but if i use this:

```
      Result = ejabberd_odbc:sql_query(Server, ["select COUNT(*) as total from users where username='", IdUsername, "';"]),
       io:format(Result),
```

i have this output:

```
    {badarg,[{io,format,[<0.42.0>,{selected,[<<"total">>],[[<<"1">>]]},[]],     []},{mod_http_offline,create_message,3,[{file,"mod_http_offline.erl"},     {line,35}]},{ejabberd_hooks,safe_apply,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},     {line,382}]},{ejabberd_hooks,run1,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},     {line,329}]},{ejabberd_sm,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_sm.erl"},     {line,111}]},{ejabberd_local,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_local.erl"},     {line,112}]},{ejabberd_router,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_router.erl"},     {line,75}]},{lists,foreach,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1336}]}]}
```

where i can see this:

```
      {selected,[<<"total">>],[[<<"1">>]]}
```

same error if i use "total" instead of <<"total">> in a case, so what is the problem? how can i get the int number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern match is:

```
{selected, [<<"total">>], [{Totale}]}
```

And the term you're matching against is:

```
{selected,[<<"total">>],[[<<"1">>]]}
```

That is, the third element in that tuple is a list containing a list containing a binary, but you're matching for a list containing a tuple.

You can get hold of that value by putting a variable name where the desired value is, like this:

```
{selected,[<<"total">>],[[Totale]]}
```

That assigns the binary to the variable `Totale`. To convert it into an integer, use [`binary_to_integer/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#binary_to_integer-1):

```
Count = binary_to_integer(Totale)
```